# What is "subject group ID" in pybliometrics?

Tags: pybliometrics

In pyblimoetric's AuthorRetrieval there is an object called `classificationgroup`.

In the [documentation](https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes/AuthorRetrieval.html) describes it as:

> List with (subject group ID, number of documents)-tuples.

But what is a "subject group ID"?

Where do I find a list of all possible "subject group ID"s and their definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are Elsevier's All Science Journal Classification (ASJC) codes.

More on that [https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12007/supporthub/scopus/~/what-are-scopus-subject-area-categories-and-asjc-codes%3F/](https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12007/supporthub/scopus/%7E/what-are-scopus-subject-area-categories-and-asjc-codes%3F/)

Scopus assigns 4-digit ASJC codes to all sources (journals, conference proceedings, books, trade journals). A source has between 1 and 7 ASJC codes. All publications in a source are assigned all the ASJC codes of the source. This implies the same publication can be counted multiple times in `.classificationgroup`.